# Word for development or improvement in art

Tags: meaning

In human race you call evolution to upgrade mankind, in technology innovation , how about the art work? how u call it? from painting to graphic design

Answer (score 8):

The words evolution and [innovation](http://www.nber.org/papers/w12185) can also describe [artistic development](http://thevirtualinstructor.com/blog/the-stages-of-artistic-development) and [breakthroughs](http://www.chicagomag.com/Chicago-Magazine/September-2010/Top-40-Artistic-Breakthroughs-Chicago-Arts-and-Culture/).Thus proper phrases in this case are *artistic [breakthrough](http://www.dw.de/young-artists-chase-elusive-breakthrough/a-16750319)* or *artistic development*. The proper word may be just the word [*development*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/development); a developed or advanced state or form:
" drama reached its highest development in the plays of Shakespeare."

Answer (score 1):

*Evolution* in a term used to refer to the developments of art though centuries:

The [evolution](http://char.txa.cornell.edu/art/introart.htm)  of visual art:

> - Art is created and enjoyed by many people for many reasons. However, one of the things that art does is extend and expand our shared common visual language. When new visual ideas are first introduced by the artist, they are often seen as shocking, and perhaps even as incomprehensible. However, with time the best and most effective of these ideas are accepted.
> - There is nothing harder than trying to grasp what was shocking or illuminating about certain images, or ways of making images, once the shock is gone, and we have all absorbed this bit of visual data into our own vocabularies. Artists show us new ways to see familiar things, and how to interpret new situations and events through various kinds of visual shorthand. This creation of visual language may be the artist's intention, or it may be a side effect of other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**"New media art"**

> New media art is a genre that encompasses artworks created with new media technologies, including digital art, computer graphics, computer animation, virtual art, Internet art, interactive art, video games, computer robotics, 3d printing, and art as biotechnology. The term differentiates itself by its resulting cultural objects and social events, which can be seen in opposition to those deriving from old visual arts (i.e. traditional painting, sculpture, etc.). This concern with medium is a key feature of much contemporary art and indeed many art schools and major Universities now offer majors in "New Genres" or "New Media" see Wikipedia [**New Media Art**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_media_art)

“**Emerging Art Forms**”

> If you know of Emerging Artists who are gifted in an *Emerging Art Form*, we’d like to hear about them.  The International World would like to know about them as well, and we’d like to help get the word out about who they are, and what they are creating. See [**Emerging Art Forms**](https://emergingartforms.wordpress.com/about/)